# Alternate proof to Rosenthal (3.6.5)

Tags: probability-theory

> Rosenthal (3.6.5)  Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability triple such that $\Omega$ be countable, and $\mathcal{F}=2^{\Omega}$.  Prove that it is impossible for there to exist a sequence $A_1, A_2, \dots \in \mathcal{F}$ which is independent, such that $P(A_i) = 1/2$ for each $i$. [Hint: first prove that for each $\omega \in \Omega$, and each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $ \displaystyle P(\{\omega\}) \leq \frac{1}{2^n} \bigg]$

I have proved this by taking $\omega \in \cap_i A_i$ then taking the probability of each and proving the hint from which the contradiction follows as the only possible value less than $1/2^n$ is zero and we get a contradiction looking at the sum of each $\omega$ and at $P(\Omega)$. I think this is the right way.

What I mean to ask is a classmate of mine said she proved it using a Borel-Cantelli lemma, which I do not see we can apply that here, as that is for $A_i$ occurring infinitely often.  So can we use that to prove this too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is not exactly good. But it is closed to the correct answer. Let $\omega\in \Omega$, for every $i$, $\omega\in A_i$ or $\omega\in \bar A_i$. We denote $B^{\omega}_i=A_i$ if $\omega\in A_i$ otherwise $B^{\omega}_i=\bar A_i$. Remark that $P(B^{\omega}_i)=1/2$ also. Thus $\omega\in \cap_iB_i$. Since $B_1,...,B_n$ are independent, it implies that $P(\omega)\leq P(\cap_iB^{\omega}_i)=1/2^n$ for every integer $n$, so $P(\omega)=0$.

Let $C_i^{\omega}=A_i$ if $\omega$ is not an element of $A_i$ otherwise $C_i^{\omega}$ is the complementary of $A_i$. Again, $P(C_i^{\omega})=1/2$. The second lemma of Borel-Cantelli implies that $P(limSup C_i^{\omega})=1$ since $\sum P(C_i^{\omega})=+\infty$. This implies that $P(D)=0$ where $D$ is the complementary space of $limSup C_i^{\omega}$. Since $\omega\in D$, we deduce $P(\omega)=0$.

Comment: I didn't include most of my work, just wanted to give the path i went, as my question was on the Borel-Cantelli path which you answered, thank you @TsemoAristide